# Update a bearer token in a watsonx extension

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I have an assistant on Watsonx that needs to use an extension with token bearer authentication. When configuring the new extension, Watson asks for the token. However, the token is only valid for 24 hours. How do I update it without manually going through the extension settings?

[image: form image]

I've already looked for a way to change the token in requests but I haven't found it. I imagined that with each request I could enter the token and thus control its validity. Updating if necessary.

How do I do this please?

Comment: Could you add more details? Is that a developer API token or one for the end user? You can pass values to the extension as part of the request. Those are typically defined as part of the extension's OpenAPI spec.

Answer (score 0):

if your use case is not one of the oauth grant types supported by watsonx assistant, then you should use the custom oauth.

For examples see https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/assistant-toolkit/tree/master/integrations/extensions/starter-kits/testitall